# Tp link TL-ER604W v1.0 locks up every 10 days or so

Tags: router, reboot, load-balancer

I have had some issues with two different TP-Link load balancing routers. The older one which had 4 WAN ports would lock up and require a reboot every week. I upgraded and bought the newer TL-ER604W v1.0 which has dual WAN and gigabit ports, I was quite happy with it until I finally set up all my servers. It lasted about 12 days out of the box then it required a reboot. I have searched all over the Internet and could not find any working solutions to fix the issue, TP Link has not updated the firmware in 2 years and it doesnt look likely that they will. Any possible solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So I figured out how to write a small script on my Mac-Mini which is connected to the router by ethernet it reboots the system automatically. I want to help the countless others who had unanswered forum posts on the tp-link website regardless of their level of competence with scripting so bare with Im going to take baby steps. This should work on Linux, Unix (Mac) or Windows with CygWin.

1.In the command prompt type `sudo nano tplink_reboot.sh`

2.Paste the following into the new file `(sleep 3;echo admin;sleep 3;echo routerpassword;sleep 3;echo enable;sleep 3;echo admin;sleep 3;echo sys reboot;sleep 3;echo y;sleep 3;) | telnet 192.168.0.1` hit ctrl+x y to save.

Change the value for "routerpassword" to the password you use to login to router and the IP address at the end to your routers IP address. It prompts you for a password later leave the input as admin, I have tested it on this router model.

3.make the file executable by typing `sudo chmod 755 tplink_reboot.sh`

4. test it out by executing the command `./tplink_reboot.sh`

Telnet is slow it takes upto 3 seconds to initially connect on my network. The script does the following start telnet connection to 192.168.0.1 >> wait 3 seconds >> send username admin >> wait 3 seconds >> send password routerpassword >> wait 3 seconds >> send enable command >> wait 3 seconds >> send password admin >> wait 3 seconds >> send sys reboot command >> wait 3 seconds >> Send confirmation y.

5. If everything is working fine you can add the following line to your cron so it executes automatically windows users can schedule the .vbs file to execute automatically by creating a basic windows task.

   crontab -e

paste the following line, save and exit

```
1 10 * * * (sleep 15;echo admin;sleep 3;echo routerpassword;sleep 3;echo enable;sleep 3;echo admin;sleep 3;echo sys reboot;sleep 3;echo y;sleep 3;) | telnet 192.168.0.1
```

This makes my mac run the script automatically everyday at 10:01 AM.

I hope this helps other people with a similar problem. This might not help if you require your services to never be down, In my case I just want my network to be accessible when I access it through my vpn server. The problem was that the WAN router would require a reboot and in the meantime lost connection to the internet so there was no way of remotely accessing it from outside my LAN, Having a machine on the local LAN run a script everyday assures that my router wont be down for longer than 24 hours ever.

Comment: "_...so bare with_" Are you asking people to get naked, or do you mean, "so bear with?"

Comment: Why would I ask people to get naked before writing a script? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If it's under warranty, I'd try sending it back.

Aside from that, I'd give a try at [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) or [DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com/) if I were you, these saved my life a couple of times! (these might void your warranty though)

Comment: I tried those options but non of the open source software supports my router.

Comment: can the router be returned? If so, I'd consider doing so and getting a router that is supported with similar specs! At least, it would give you choices, right?

Comment: yeah I decided to do just that, because the wifi keeps dropping out now. would not recommend this model to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

This hanging of the router, seems to be a general problem. I have it also with a TL-ER604W v2.0 with firmware 1.2.0 Build 20160825 Rel.45884s. I reboot it with a power switch over gsm when it hangs, which is in average every 3 weeks.